# Estimation technique for FDI "gravity" model with negative and zero observations and heteroskedasticity

Tags: econometrics, heteroscedasticity, macroeconomics

I am trying to model FDI (foreign direct investment) flows and am facing several issues;

1) There is the well-known condition that under heteroskedasticity log-linearized OLS models are biased and inconsistent. Santos-Silva and Tenreyro (2006) suggest using Poisson pseudo maximum likelihood (PPML) to overcome this, and subsequently PPML, negative binomial and Poisson modeling became commonplace in the literature, but...

2) FDI flows are often negative (divestment), which cannot be accommodated by count data models or PPML. Negative flows are economically meaningful and therefore cannot just be dropped without loss of consistency. An alternative is to use stocks rather than flows, but this does not seem to fit very well with the theory of gravity equations which seem to me to inherently deal with flow concepts.

Can anyone suggest an appropriate estimator? I have heard the suggestion of multinomial logit (where dep.var. is share of global FDI flows) but this would also seem to falter in the case of a negative flow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FDI = foreign direct investment? PPML = ? What is your starting model (the one that has problems)?

Comment: Cross-posted on Economics Stack Exchange [here](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/15184/appropriate-estimator-for-fdi-gravity-model).

Comment: I think this would best be done with a customised link function and generalised linear models. It would be surprising if no-one had tackled this before. Cube roots and neglog might help.